# How to pass output from sed into cp command?

Tags: bash, sed

Conceptually I would like to achieve sth like this:

```
sed 's|<pattern>|<replace>|' <filename> --> cp <sedoutput> <somewhere>
```

In general: 
I would like to pass every line from sed one-by-one into another command that doesn't accept piping so probably xargs doesn't apply. Perhaps sometimes I will even like to put  in more than one place in the second command's arguments list. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't accept piping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use xargs

```
sed 's|<pattern>|<replace>|' file | xargs -i{} cp {} somewhere
```

Comment: Awesome! So far I didn't know this option

Answer (score 4):

You can use `command substitution`:

```
cp "$(sed 's|<pattern>|<replace>|' filename)" somewhere
```

If sed is producing multi-line output then use `process substitution`:

```
while read -r f; do
    cp "$f" somewhere
done < <(sed 's|<pattern>|<replace>|' filename)
```

Comment: He write "each line of a sed" so the result is certainly several line where cp accept only 2 file/folder as argument (+ options/parameters) and will do unexpected result i guess

Comment: exhaustive solution +1

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's|<pattern>|<replace>|' filename | while read EachOccurrence
 do
   cp "${EachOccurrence}" "${somewhere}"
 done
```

read need maybe a `-r` is some `\` occurs in input lines